# Require dynamic module coming from server with webpack

Tags: javascript, amd, webpack, commonjs

We have an AMD application and in bootstrap script we do this

```
define(['config', '...other dependencies'], function(config) {
   // do stuff with config
});
```

where `'config'` "module" is mapped to `/config` route in server application, allowing us to configure our application on server-side.

I'm integrating webpack into our system and can not make this work. It seems that webpack assumes every dependency module is a file on disk.

Did I miss something? Maybe there's a loader or specific configuration for this case?

**EDIT**:

I noticed a guy asking a very similar question in comments to this doc article: http://webpack.github.io/docs/amd.html:

> How can we make webpack work with an AMD module written like this?

```
define([
  'async!//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry'
  ], function () {
    return google.maps;
 });
```

This would answer my question as well it seems.